# IPython qtconsole highlighting

Tags: ipython, pygments

I am using the IPython qtconsole and the directories are dark blue and I can't seem to find any way to change this in the theme. I'm using pygments with the monokai theme for the syntax highlighting.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This coloring is actually done by `ls` itself.
You can use the LSCOLORS ( on OS X / BSD, or LS_COLORS on Linux) environment variable to customize this.
Here is a [nifty utility](http://geoff.greer.fm/lscolors/) for generating an LSCOLORS value.
You can probably Google-about for peoples favored dark-background LSCOLORS values.

Then just set the variable, either in Python:

```
import os
os.environ['LSCOLORS'] = 'gxfxcxdxbxegedabagacad'
```

or in your shell session prior to launching IPython (or .bashrc, etc.):

```
$> export LSCOLORS=gxfxcxdxbxegedabagacad
$> ipython qtconsole
```

see also: [reference docs for LS_COLORS](http://linux-sxs.org/housekeeping/lscolors.html)

Comment: Awesome, this will save the strain on my eyes! I even like the color you chose :)

Comment: All I did was take the defaults from the linked generator and click cyan for directories, but I'm glad you like it!